# How to turn webpages into pdf?

Tags: internet, pdf, webpage

I mean saving them as a pdf and keep them as a backup for future reference or for future reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are online converters such as:

[web2pdf.co.uk](http://www.web2pdf.co.uk/)

Comment: This website has been removed.

Answer (score 10):

You could install [CutePDF printer driver](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp), and print the pages you want to PDF files.

Alternatively, there exist [quite](http://www.surfoffline.com/) [some](http://www.offlinedownloader.com/) [tools](http://www.internet-soft.com/extractor.htm) to download and store full websites.

Comment: similar method: print to file using a PostScript printer driver, then convert the resulting file with `ps2pdf`.  this was handy way-back-when when PDF printer drivers only came from Adobe but Microsoft provided a great postscript driver for Apple Laserwriters for free.  :)

Answer (score 4):

From sourceforge:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

In case you are using firefox browser, this addin is a good one:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5971?src=api

Answer (score 1):

This is my favourite - converts everything (documents, websites, emails etc)

http://www.freepdfconvert.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert a webpage to PDF in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save web pages for future reference or future reading I find best to use the [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427) Addon in Firefox or save the webpage as .mht file (native in IE, possible in Firefox using [UnMHT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8051) Addon).

These methods will save your page with more accuracy than printing them to pdf.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-to-PDF is a free utility for batch converting webpages to PDF documents from the command line or via a GUI...

See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-to-pdf/

It produces HTML and CSS rendering pretty much identical to that of Internet Explorer. Handles pages containing JavaScript, embeds fonts, and allows you to insert live links and live forms into a PDF document.