# How to create a PDF file from a webpage?

Tags: printing, print-to-pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn webpages into pdf?](https://superuser.com/questions/79773/how-to-turn-webpages-into-pdf)

Do you know of any application that I can use so that I can emulate a printing of a webpage?
I dont know if emulate is the correct term but here is what I want to do:

I want to print a table that is in a webpage. The problem is the default printing service of windows (print spooler) which saves the file as .xps. Do you know of any application that I can install or even a portable application that I can use so that it communicates with the web browser and creates a .pdf file of the webpage I want to print.

Comment: To remove parts of the page you might want to discard: see The Printliminator at http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/79773/how-to-turn-webpages-into-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PrintPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5971) firefox addon.
There are several more add-ons that do that.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) is a great free PDF-Printer.

Having this portable won't be possible, since it needs to register itself as a printer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several applications such as [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/download) that mimic a printer, but actually churn out a PDF file. Also, if you just want to print part of a web page, select that part and pick `Selection` from the `Print Range` option in the `Print` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cute PDF?
YTou can print the webpage to the Cute PDF printer and it will generate a PDF file.
If i read your question correctly, that is what you are wanting to do.