# Convert a Google Book into a PDF

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf

I saw this [nice question](https://superuser.com/questions/79773/how-to-turn-webpages-into-pdf) about printing webpages. When I try to apply it to this [Google Book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=5uNg_7OyhuYC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%96&source=bl&ots=rwOfAvXqPN&sig=RsP33EOFIR0kbcw7rtYsOBObxqI&hl=en&ei=mvTCTNTuHczHswbgq6TbCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%96&f=false), I see that it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: I ran across a program claiming to download Google books, but it was v0.1 and I couldn't get it to work.  Seems link it should be possible.

Comment: @Sathya - it prints an empty book

Comment: I have answered this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/659608/378310).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox browser, download the [GreeseMonkey add-on](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/37933) and grab [Google Book Downloader script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/37933).

Now you will find the `download` button whenever you browse a book in books.google.com.

Edit: The [Scriptish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/) has now superseded GreeseMonkey and should be used instead.

Comment: Looks promising, but when I click 'download' I see separate links to all pages in the book. There are 200+ pages!

Comment: So this is why google books readers all read one page at a time. If there is an easy way to download them all, it should be a simple matter to concatenate 200 PDFs into one.

Comment: If you are willing to pay $19.95, GooReader will do that for you : http://gooreader.com/.

Comment: this link appears to be dead.  is the add-on no longer available?

Comment: i've confirmed it's no longer available.

Comment: @dbliss: See my edit above.

Comment: sorry, i guess i wasn't clear.  the Google Book Downloader script is no longer available.

Comment: @dbliss: I switched the link to the userscripts mirror. It should work now.

Comment: it does work, but, weirdly, when i use firefox as required for this script, i am able to preview fewer pages than i can with chrome (which is what i had been using).

Comment: for that reason, i'm using the hacky solution i posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/659608/378310), which gets me all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [GreaseMonkey](http://greasefire.userscripts.org/scripts/show/37933) Script Which lets You Download Google Books as **Individual JPGs** (One Page = One Jpg file). You Can Download all the book pages as a Jpg Files then Turn them Into A PDF file Using OpenOffice or any other Software.

**Edit:** You Also Can Try [Google Book Downloader](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Google-Book-Downloader-Download-112996.html) Which is a software that lets you save Google Books as PDF Files, But Please Read this Note First:

> This version allows to download books marked as to full view (but it does not mean you can download it from google). You can try download books without this mark, but not all pages will be downloaded.

Comment: that greasemonkey script is no longer available.