# Is there a way to save a webpage exactly as you would view it in a browser, but in PDF form?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, webpage

Very often, I try to archive pages (such as [this](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/current-limiter-circuit.php) one) or web forums by saving an offline PDF copy, but end up having the format messed up where text is missing as shown below.

I am using either Google Chrome (Windows) or Chromium (Linux) browsers.
My current solution for situations like this is to replicate the page manually by copy and pasting the text and do partial screen captures of images,
or when that is not practical, screen capture everything page by page, and then converting the result to one PDF.

Would there be a better alternative for formatting issues when trying to archive webpages offline as a PDF?

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/q/79773/152004)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a webpage to PDF with preserving its look (exactly as on web browser) and text/links?](https://superuser.com/questions/1064579/how-to-convert-a-webpage-to-pdf-with-preserving-its-look-exactly-as-on-web-brow)

Comment: I tried most of the suggestions, especially the "wkhtmltopdf" tool; but resulted in an error output for the particular page asked in this topic. If I find the solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

In the "More settings" section of the Print menu, set the "Scale" factor to a customized value.

In this case 59% worked for me with the web page you linked to.

As for why this is necessary, I hope someone else can explain.
(If they do, accept their answer, not this one.)

Comment: It makes the text smaller too, but that could be an acceptable compromise under some circumstances.

Comment: @plu, quoting myself from two days ago on another SE site: "accepting an answer (i.e. the check mark you just selected) shouldn't normally be done for at least 24 hours after the question has been asked. This gives everyone around the world a chance to see and answer the question. And once a question has been marked as accepted, many people won't bother to read the question as they know it already has an excellent answer. This means that you might now miss out on an answer that is a lot better than mine."

Comment: // Thanks, I did not realize an "accepted answer" had that effect. I'll see if undo-ing it would allow better answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that unfortunately does not always work, it depends on the site. Anyway you can try to print the page using the **print to file** option.